# @POST method of REST service developed with Resteasy

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I am developing a client/server application.
Server-side I am using Java EE, and Resteasy as library to develop REST web-service. Client-side I have written a simple HTML page to query these backend services.
All services I have done work properly, except one, a @POST service.

The code of it is:

```
@OPTIONS
@Override
@POST
@Path("/{id}/jobs")
public void print(@PathParam("id") String deviceId,
    @FormParam("doc") byte[] doc,
    @FormParam("copies") int copies)
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the array of byte that I am sending from the frontend to the backend arrives, but when arrives it is null. The other input parameters arrive correctly to the backend.

I think that this problem can be solved defining a @Consumes on the method, but I don't know which "application" type I should use. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 1):

From the [@FormParam](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) documentation:

> The type T of the annotated parameter must either:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type
> 2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single >String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
> 4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload a file too? That's why are you using the doc byte[] parameter, right? In this case, you're right, you need to use the @Consumes annotation like this:

```
@OPTIONS
@Override
@POST
@Path("/{id}/jobs")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void print(@FormDataParam("doc") InputStream is, 
    @FormDataParam("doc") FormDataContentDisposition formData,
    @PathParam("id") String deviceId,
    @FormParam("copies") int copies)
{
    //code to process your InputStream to get your byte[]
    ...
}
```

And this will be your html:

```
<form action="yourPath/yourId/jobs" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   File : <input type="file" name="doc" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The importan code is the "encytype" attribute in your form, @Consumes annotation, and @FormDataParam to receive the file data that you uploaded.
You can see a complete example [here](http://www.concretepage.com/webservices/upload-file-using-restful-web-services-jax-rs)